# Dahon D7HG Handlepost hinge loosens pivot point

Tags: maintenance

I have a Dahon Vittese D7 HG, bought in Perú 1 year ago, my handlepost hinge begins to sound like crack , then I supposed that it could be because the friction between steel parts, and adjustment on my handlepost. I had the great idea to put a thinner rubber on the joint press.

Now, I am feeling some movements in my handlepost pivot point (please see photo).[image: dahon d7hg handlepost hinge pivot point]
Could it be normal? I dont remember that, because after the rubber, I feel totally silence in my bike.

Answer (score 1):

Please review the following two references as it possibly your D7 may be fall within the questionable Dahon models:

http://www.performancebike.com/images/performance/web/pdfs/Dahon_Folding_recall2009.pdf

and

http://www.thorusa.com/dahon/technical/recall.pdf

(Dahon enthusiasts have a blog as well that may be accessed through the manufacturer's website and is useful for service tips as well.)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for sharing and sorry to hear of your issue. You can take the bike to any local dealer for assistance, contact [Dahon Peru](https://www.facebook.com/dahonperu?fref=ts) for stores. If bought last year it is not likely to be affected by the recall, but if you are worried please email your serial number to contact@dahon.com and we will check. Thanks! Willow